# Unable to connect to micro service through ZUUL api gateway in docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, netflix-zuul

I've following services and working fine when they are deployed in localhost (through eclipse). But unable to invoke the rest service when deployed as separate docker containers.

I'm new docker and attended the tutorials to have knowledge on how this works.

Following services are running in separate docker containers and configured as follows (local environment)

Eureka

```
Docker IP : 172.17.0.3
Docker port mapping : 8761:8761

spring.application.name=naming-server
server.port=8761
```

Zuul API gate way

```
Docker IP : 172.17.0.4
Docker port mapping : 8765:8765

spring.application.name=gateway-server
server.port=8765
```

User service

```
Docker IP : 172.17.0.5
Docker port mapping : 8101:8101

spring.application.name=user-service
server.port=8101
```

Registered services info in Eureka

Application         AMIs    Availability Zones  Status

USER-SERVICE        n/a (1) (1)                 UP (1) - de4396a354ea:user-service:8101

API-GATEWAY         n/a (1) (1)                 UP (1) - e5dd509065cd:api-gateway:8765

When tried to invoke the service in "User service" through gateway, it's throwing exception

```
    com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:198) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:173) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]

    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: de4396a354ea: Name or service not known
        at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515) ~[na:na]
```

Note: "de4396a354ea" is the container id for "User service"

Please guide on how to resolve this issue and also provide any links where I can get more info regarding deploying microservices in docker containers.

Answer (score 1):

Able to resolve this by adding "eureka.instance.hostname=" property.